# Wordpress Error PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm tryig to change something on my widget but not working widget page in admin.

Showing this error

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string in
>
> /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/general-template.php on line 4230

About the 4230 general-template source code is this,

```
function __checked_selected_helper( $helper, $current, $echo, $type ) {
    if ( (string) $helper === (string) $current )
        $result = " $type='$type'";
    else
        $result = '';

    if ( $echo )
        echo $result;

    return $result;
}
```

I try disable plugins and change template but still same problem.

Comment: Can you var_dump `$helper` and `$current`? I get the feeling you are trying to type cast an object to a string, which is not possible.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to convert an object to a string, which could issue this error.

Comment: did you call this `WP_Term ` in your code?

Comment: Well... @Kevinvhengst beat me to it.

Comment: try `if ( $helper ===  $current )` and remove `if ( $echo )
        echo $result;` as `echo ` and `return` cannot be together

Comment: Also - I guess that you aren't gonna get your desired $result? is it not supposed to be  `$result = "$type=".$type;`    ?

Comment: @AlivetoDie solutions is work when i change  (string) $helper === (string) $current to  $helper === $current  working well :)

Comment: @Stender  actually it's ok:- https://eval.in/940535.  But yes it's actually seems useless in current scenario (But who know why OP have that)

Comment: @ZgrKARALAR  i have added as a solution . As well as take care of note section too

Comment: @AlivetoDie thank you to solution

Comment: @alivetoDie ahh - it is because it is desired to be quoted! I've never seen it like that before - I have done something like this `echo $result = " $type=\"$type\""; ` or - `echo $result = ' $type="'.$type.'"';`

Comment: @Stender  now you got a new thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your are converting two objects to string unnecessarly.

So change:-

```
if ( (string) $helper === (string) $current )
```

to:-

```
if ( $helper === $current )
```

***Note:-*** remove `if ( $echo ) echo $result;` as `echo` and `return` cannot be together

Comment: Without change echo result, not working well for that better to change also as @alivetodie say if echo